# Android - Close popUpWindow when clicked outside of the view

Tags: android, popupwindow

I have a small problem with the popup window functionality.I would like to close it when the user clicks outside of the window.I have read a lots of atricle on stackoverflow, but not a single articles helped me. What I have tried is, I have tried to popupwindow.setBackgroundDrawable(null); which is not worked for me.

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popupmenu_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popuplinearlayout));
    pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 300, true);
    pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    pw.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    //Todo remove popup window when outside is touched...
```

If you know a good article what may help me I would appreciate it.It is posible this features is not working in emulator ? I have only emulator right now.(android 4.4.2)

Answer (score 1):

And if Marcin's constructor is deprecated, use

```
pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
pw.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

do

```
pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
```

Answer (score 0):

use `pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),""));`

Set window background transtarent.

`pw.getBackground().setAlpha(0);`

Comment: did you try the answer i posted? accept it if it works for you